# How maintain a button font size constantly when new line is available

Tags: java, android

This attached screen is the activity screen I want to create. But I have a problem with the button changing the line. I want my button created by entering text data automatically change line while maintaining font size. How can I make this?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to check this blog https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/

Comment: Elaborate on your problem. Are you discussing about Buttons or Chips? They are different UI components.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Thank you for answer. I didn't know much about chips. Your answers helped me solve the problem.

Comment: @Swayangjit Thanks for your help, I was able to solve the problem. Thank you!